# How to replace all rows of a dataframe with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace `100` with `NaN` in a dataframe with 2 columns but for some reason it replaces only the first 3 rows of the first column. What could be the reason?

This is my code and the output:

```
print('Before', df, type(df))
df = df.replace(100, np.nan)
print('After', df)

Before                                             A             B
2020-09-17 00:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
2020-09-18 00:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
2020-09-18 01:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
2020-09-18 02:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
2020-09-18 03:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
...                                              ...           ...
2020-10-03 04:00:00+00:00                  99.916528     96.116235
2020-10-03 05:00:00+00:00                  99.933531     95.525355
2020-10-03 06:00:00+00:00                  99.942923     95.756569
2020-10-03 07:00:00+00:00                  99.940998     95.721852
2020-10-03 08:00:00+00:00                  99.941141     95.099550

[370 rows x 2 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
After                                              A             B
2020-09-17 00:00:00+00:00                        NaN           NaN
2020-09-18 00:00:00+00:00                        NaN           NaN
2020-09-18 01:00:00+00:00                        NaN           NaN
2020-09-18 02:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
2020-09-18 03:00:00+00:00                 100.000000           NaN
...                                              ...           ...
2020-10-03 04:00:00+00:00                  99.916528     96.116235
2020-10-03 05:00:00+00:00                  99.933531     95.525355
2020-10-03 06:00:00+00:00                  99.942923     95.756569
2020-10-03 07:00:00+00:00                  99.940998     95.721852
2020-10-03 08:00:00+00:00                  99.941141     95.099550
```

When I print `df['A']` it says dtype is `float64` so I have no clue how to solve this issue. And iterating through columns doesn't give the expected result neither.

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].replace(100, np.nan)
```

Comment: Can you add `df["A"].dtypes` to the question?

Comment: I would try to convert the column to integer before applying the replace or use some round for the column

Comment: @Ch3steR `print(df["A"].dtypes)` returns `float64`, same for column `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-replaced values are of course those which are not **exactly** 100.

Pandas default representation for floating-point numbers is 6 digits after the decimal point. Try to extend it (for example to 20 digits):

```
pd.set_option("display.float_format", "{:.20f}".format)
```

before displaying your dataframe to see those non-exact values.